# Does txn.get("somekey") occupy the RAM for the rest of the python script? if yes how to free the RAM it uses?

Tags: python, database, ram, lmdb

I have a script where I am trying to append data to an existing key/value pair. The problem is that whenever I get the existing data using `txn.get()`, it uses RAM that it doesn't free afterwards. When the limit of RAM approaches the computer gets extremely slow and the swap space is used more and more. For now I did not reached the limit of the swap space but I am afraid my script will stop running if it reaches the limit. But either way, without that RAM usage my script will run smoothly even with a small RAM.

Here is a snippet of my script causing me this problem:

```
for p in xrange(strings_number):  
    data=txn.get(struct.pack('i',900000+p))  #I want to reorganize this bytestring into columns
    for j in xrange(col_number):
        to_be_appended=""
        for l in xrange(j*4,len(data),size):
            to_be_appended+=data[l:l+4]
        temp=txn.get(struct.pack('i',j))  #whenever I call txn.get() memory usage gets bigger
        txn.put(struct.pack('i',j),temp+to_be_appended,dupdata=False,overwrite=True)         
        txn.delete(struct.pack('i',900000+p))
```

Comment: Related but not a dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python . I think thats relevant here in that you could call `gc.collect()` after each loop iteration and see if it helps. Note that GC will use CPU time while it GCs. I'm not optimistic that this will help your situation though.

Comment: Sadly gc.collect() doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: In that case you need to change your code to keep less data in memory